# multiple NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

whiling installing cuda on our ubuntu 14.04 machine,
(by the way, I later found NVIDIA driver 387.22 had been installed using .run file previously.)
I found maybe there are multiple NVIDIA drivers installed in the system.

```
ckim@ab1:~/samples/0_Simple/clock$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.7, 4.4.0-104-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 4.4.0-109-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.4.0-104-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.4.0-109-generic, x86_64: installed

ckim@ab1:~/samples/0_Simple/clock$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  387.22  Wed Oct 25 23:13:21 PDT 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

It seems like 384.111 and 387.22 are installed together. I tried installing cuda 8.0 using .deb file. What is this situation and to install cuda properly ( I get error 30 in cudGetDevCount()), what should I do?

If I remove the .run installed driver, will the driver module (384.111) take control automatically?